# AUCTeX does not recognize cleveref labels

Tags: cleveref, emacs, auctex, reftex

I use the cleveref package, which allows annotating `\label` commands with
an optional argument. Unfortunately, this prevents the various functions in
`latex.el` from detecting those labels. My guess is that it is because they do not match the built-in regexp for labels.

Some example LaTeX code to illustrate the situation:

```latex
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{diagram}{diagram}{diagrams}
% ...
\begin{equation}
  \label[diagram]{eq:23}
  1 = 1
\end{equation}
```

AUCTeX will not notice that I have used `eq:23`, and then if I try to
automatically generate labels, it will again propose `eq:23`.

Digging around in the AUCTeX sources, I found the following in `latex.el`:

```el
(defvar LaTeX-auto-label-regexp-list
  '(("\\\\label{\\([^^M\n\r%\\{}]+\\)}" 1 LaTeX-auto-label))
  "List of regular expression matching LaTeX labels only.")
```

This seems to be the appropriate variable to extend. However, I can't seem to get the regexp right. I have tried adding the following to my emacs config before AUCTeX gets loaded (and it appears in the output of `describe-variable` for `LaTeX-auto-label-regexp-list`), but AUCTeX is still not recognizing the above as labels.

```el
(setq LaTeX-auto-label-regexp-list
  '(("\\\\label{\\([^^M%\\{}]+\\)}" 1 LaTeX-auto-label)
  ("\\\\label\\[[^^M[\\{}]+\\]{\\([^^M%\\{}]+\\)}" 1 LaTeX-auto-label)))
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Not at my computer, but try moving your first `^M` right after the following `[` (in the regexp you added).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but no luck. I built the regexp using emacs's `re-builder`, and it correctly matches `\label[abc]{eq:3}` for example.

Comment: I wonder if it's really AUCTeX that is automatically generating your labels. How do you do it? Aren't you using RefTeX? If so, maybe `LaTeX-auto-label-regexp-list` is used for something else in AUCTeX, such as fontification.

Comment: Good catch @frougon . RefTeX's `reftex-label` function is what seems to actually generate the labels, and I think it uses `reftex-parse-from-file` to figure out existing labels. Unfortunately, it hard-codes the `\label{` prefix. I've filed a wishlist bug report. I'll update the question with an answer if ever it gets fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within AUCTeX, `latex.el` provides support for vanilla LaTeX.  Additions by packages are catered via AUCTeX style files.  In this case, this is a shortcoming in `cleveref.el` which didn't have support for an optional argument in `\label` macro.  This issue [is now fixed](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/?id=8530cd0c25d07c182ccef54bee5645cc309cce62) and will be available with next AUCTeX release.

If you want to use it now, customize the variable `TeX-style-private` to a directory of your choice and save the [updated style](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/plain/style/cleveref.el) there.  Restart Emacs and AUCTeX will use the new version.  Just keep in mind to remove it once a new AUCTeX version is out.